# Idiomatic AngularJS modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting to grips with AngularJS - and in my struggle I've read that **$broadcast/$emit** is overused. Having worked with Backbone in the past, this service seems like a natural replacement for **pubSub**, a standard goto for decoupled components outside of Angular.

In this instance, i want to render a modal overlay in response to network events and user input. Let's say I have this:

```
angular
    .module("app.controllers")
    .controller("ModalCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
         // or a directive?
         $scope.modal = {
             title: "",
             visibility: ""
         };
    });
```

Wrapping this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ModalCtrl" class="modal {{visibility}}">
    <h2 data-ng-bind="modal.title"></h2>
</div>
```

How should I go about altering the visibility of this component from another - i.e. this:

```
angular
    .module("app.controllers")
    .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, ModalCtrl) {

        $scope.handleClick = function () {
            // this:
            $rootScope.$broadcast("modal", {
                title: "ClickHandler",
                visibility: "is-visible"
            });

            // or this? modify scope directly
            $rootScope.modal = {
                title: "ClickHandler",
                visibility: "is-visible"
            };

            // or this? - assuming I can pass it in as a dependency
            ModalCtrl.show({title: "ClickHandler});
        };

    });
```

Comment: This is a good question IMHO but belongs on SO.

Comment: In the MVW Angular's pattern, it's bad practice to find a way to make separate controllers communicating. You could make an intermediary service that could be injected in `ModalCtrl` as well as any other controller.

Comment: could you demonstrate that approach with some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MVW Angular's pattern, it's bad practice to find a way to make separate controllers communicating. You could make an intermediary service that could be injected in ModalCtrl as well as any other controller.

For example, let's introduce `ModalService`:

```
// Services
angular
    .module("app.services")
    .factory("ModalService", function () {
        var ModalService = {
            modal: {
                title: "",
                visibility: ""
            }
        };
        return ModalService;
    });

// Controllers, depending on services
angular
    .module("app.controllers", ["app.services"])
    .controller("ModalCtrl", function ($scope, ModalService) {
         $scope.modal = ModalService.modal;
    });
    .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, ModalService) {
        $scope.handleClick = function () {
            ModalService.modal.title = "ClickHandler";
            ModalService.modal.visibility = "is-visible";
        };
    });
```

This is a simple illustration. Note that it's nicer for a service to expose functions rather that structures directly. It did expose a structure in order to clearly explain my point.